# How to import a chart from Open Office to Google Document

Tags: google-drive, google-docs

I made a chart in Open Office 4.0.0 and tried to copy and paste it into a document in Google Drive. It showed the loading sign but just loads a blank image. How can I copy and paste into the Google Document?

Comment: Can try with this extension http://extensions.openoffice.org/en/project/openofficeorg2googledocs-export-import-google-docs-zoho-webdav

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try exporting the chart as a PNG file, then inserting that into a Google Doc.